# calculate standard deviation for cumulative sum

Tags: standard-deviation, error-propagation

I have data which is x and y as shown below. x and y have standard deviation x_sd and y_sd.
I have calculated cumulative sum for x, and x*y as shown below (x_cumsum & xy).
Now I need to calculate the standard deviation for cumulative sum and xy.
I new to statistics, please help!!

```
x   x_sd    y   y_sd    x_cumsum    x_cumsum_sd     xy   xy_sd
2.4 0.3   2.0   0.2      2.4                       4.8  
2.5 0.5   4.2   0.2      4.9                      10.5  
2.8 0.1   6.4   0.3      2.8                      17.9  
3.2 0.1   8.4   0.3      6.0                      26.9  
3.6 0.7  10.0   0.4      3.6                      36.5  
3.9 0.09 11.1   0.4      7.6                      43.4  
4.5 0.6  11.1   0.5      4.5                      50.3  
4.9 0.4  10.7   0.5      9.4                      52.0  
4.3 0.3  10.2   0.5      4.3                      44.1  
3.6 0.3  9.9    0.6      7.9                      35.2  
3.9 0.2  10.4   0.6      3.9                      40.8
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is this for? Unless you have an unusual joint distribution for $\{x_t\}$, calculating the sample standard deviation of the cumulative sum is *NOT* a sensical thing to do because $y_t = x_t + y_{t-1}$ is [not stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process). The standard deviation of $y$ does not exist. As your number of observations $n$ increases, your calculation of the sample standard deviation using $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ won't converge to something useful, it will increase in an unbounded fashion, wander off to infinity.

Comment: Additionally, your table has errors in it. For one, `x_cumsum` isn't calculated properly.

Comment: Ya!! Now i understand that I asked a stupid question. It doesn't make any sense to calculate this. Sorry. Thanks for your time @MatthewGunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer a related, reinterpreted version of your question.

#### Is it sensible to calculate the sample standard deviation of the cumulative sum of a white noise process?

No.

Imagine $\{\epsilon_t\}$ is a *white noise process*, that is, mean zero and serially uncorrelated:

$$\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t] = 0 \quad \quad \mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t \epsilon_{t-j}] = 0 \text{ for }j \neq 0$$

Then $y_t = y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, the cumulative sum of $\epsilon_t$, is a non-stationary process, and neither a finite unconditional mean $\operatorname{E}[y]$ nor a finite standard beviation $\operatorname{Stdev}[y]$ exist.

Furthermore, the *sample mean* or *sample standard deviation*, won't converge on anything useful as your number of observations $T$ increase. They'll go off to infinity.

The same result holds if $y_t$ has a drift term $y_t = y_{t-1} + a + \epsilon_t$.